Borrar datos antiguos de ambas tablas con FK en MySQL
Lo que requiero es borrar todos los datos antiguos de mis tablas: el detalle está que están unidas por FK o restricciones de clave foránea.
Esta es mi tabla principal pero no puedo borrar los datos por el FK...
Quiero saber qué acciones ya tienen mucho tiempo como para borrarlas...
SELECT `idaccion` 
FROM `accion` 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `fecha`, CURDATE()) > 88

Mi otra tabla contiene los movimientos, aquí las uno y muestro ambos contenidos y esto es lo que requiero eliminar...
SELECT `a`.`*`, `b`.`*`
FROM `accion` `a`
INNER JOIN `movimiento` `b` ON `a`.`idaccion` = `b`.`idaccion`
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `fecha`, CURDATE()) > 88

¿Cómo convierto la consulta en un DELETE sin que me afecte la FK?
O ¿cómo borro los movimientos movimientos primero?
Esta consulta borraría las acciones si no tuviera el FK de movimiento...
DELETE FROM `accion`
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `fecha`, CURDATE()) > 88


Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Muestra un esquema completo, que incluya los CREATE TABLE de todas las tablas implicadas en este asunto. Si hay tablas que dependen de otras, ocurrirá lo que esté indicado en la definición de integridad referencial de esas tablas. Si quieres un comportamiento distinto, entonces quizá deberás redefinir las restricciones de integridad referencial, para que el comportamiento sea ese cuando ocurra un DELETE. Revisa esta respuesta para entender cómo funciona la integridad referencial.

Me estaré oxidando? Se supone que para borrar algo con FKs primero borras en las tablas secundarias (movimientos) y luego si quieres en las primarias (acciones), o por lo menos yo he hecho eso y no he tenido problemas...

Intente una eliminación de múltiples tablas (Multi-Table Deletes), ver dbfiddle. Las estructuras de las tablas son ficticias para ajustarlas al ejemplo.
